# The regular expression works with Chrome and Firefox browsers but not on safari

Tags: regex, safari

This is the RegEx.

```js
/^[a-zA-Z]+(?!.*?\.\.)(?!.*?\-\-)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*(?<!\.)(?<!\-)$/
```

It works with Chrome and Firefox browsers but fails on Safari browser with the error:

> Invalid *regular expression:invalid group specifier name*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should understand what your regex pattern does (or matches).

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `(?!.*?\.\.)` - no two consecutive dots allowed after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?!.*?\-\-)` - no two consecutive dots allowed after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*` - zero or more letters, digits, `.` or `-`
- `(?<!\.)(?<!\-)$` - the end of string with no `.` nor `-` immediately on the left.

So, what you want to match is a string that starts with letters, then contains alphanumeric chars "interleaved" with dots or hyphens, but `--` and `..` are forbidden.

The identical pattern without a lookbehind will look like

```js
/^[a-zA-Z](?!.*?\.\.)(?!.*?--)(?!.*[.-]$)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$/
```

Here, `(?!.*[.-]$)` requires to fail the match if there is a `.` `or` -`at the end of the string.  You should also emove the first`+`, it will allow backtracking when it is not necessary.

**NOTE** that the pattern above allows `.-` and `-.` in the string. If you do not want to allow that, simply use a no-lookaround pattern,

```js
/^[a-z]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*$/i
```

The `^[a-z]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*$` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - one or more letters (case insensitive matching is enabled with `/i` flag)
- `(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of `-` or `.` and then one or more letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. This suggestion worked.

Comment: Can we use regular expression in firefox' search? How?

Comment: @JJoao Using CTRL+F? No, there is no way :)

Comment: @JJoao The question is about using a regex in JavaScript that is interpreted/run inside a specific browser. Anyway, it is obsolete now since lookbehinds have been supported by Safari starting with Version 13.